# How do I discover the Oracle Express workspace name?

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe, oracle-apex

Is there a way to discover the WORKSPACE name if I've forgotten it?

I cannot login to the APEX admin console since I've forgotten what the workspace name was.

I do know the `SYSTEM` user password.

Could you please help me recovering my workspace name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two tables you can get this info from.

`APEX_WORKSPACES` and `APEX_APPLICATIONS`.

The schema that these tables reside in depends on the APEX version. By way of example, my vanilla Oracle 11.2 install has them in the `APEX_030200` schema. To list: `select USERNAME from DBA_USERS where USERNAME like 'APEX%'`.

Comment: Thanks Phil...I was able to find my Workspace name. Now even after giving in the right workspace, I am not able to log in. I am logging in using SYSTEM user. I am supplying the right password because using the same password I can log in to SQLPLUS....What could i try now? Please help

Comment: The APEX admin user is completely different to the database SYSTEM user. From sqlplus, run `$ORACLE_HOME/apex/apxconf.sql` to reset the APEX admin password.

Answer (score 2):

In APEX 4, the following are defaults:

```
WORKSPACE = INTERNAL
USER = ADMIN
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm maybe missing something too obvious to ask, but how can I query those "two tables" from a system I cannot access in the first place?

Comment: Please use Edit button at bottom of you question to add this to it.